# Unable to render React page after refresh, instead showing raw data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

everyone! I am trying to build an app using Node/React/Mongoose without CRA command that also includes custom webpack.

I managed to build everything in a single React page (App.jsx), but the code looks messy. I managed to build it by fetching the data from database first, and later building everything around it. Now that works, but I wanted to go one step further. I wanted to build an app regardless of the data being fetched.

Now, the problem I found myself having is maybe better to show in a slideshow. How do I solve this issue? I've tried changing the paths, but no luck.

Once I am on a homepage, navbar is being rendered. I can also refresh, and it won't break.
[image]

When I use navbar to navigate to a /teacher, it loads everything nicely.

[image]

But the problem starts when I refresh OR type the url localhost8080/teacher manually. Instead of a component, it fetches the raw data.

[image]

This is my code relevant to the issue:

server.js

```
app.use('/teacher', authRoutes);
app.use('/class', classRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../docs/index.html"))

})
```

routes.js

```
router.get('/signup', authController.teacherList);
```

controller

```
exports.teacherList = (req, res, next) => {
    Teacher.find()
    .then(teacher => {
        return res.send(teacher)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import TeacherComponent from './Teacher'
import ClassComponent from './Class'

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {    
      return (
    <Router>
        <div>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li><Link to={'/class'} className="nav-link">Class</Link></li>
            <li><Link to={'/teacher'} className="nav-link">Teacher</Link></li>
          </ul>
          </nav>
          <hr />
          <Routes>
              <Route path='/class' element={<ClassComponent />} />
              <Route path='/teacher' element={<TeacherComponent />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
      );
    }
  }
```

Teacher.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import Select from 'react-select';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class Teacher extends Component {
  
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          teachers: [],
          isSignedUp: false,
          firstName : '',
          lastName: '',
          email: '',
          password: '',
          studentsClass: {
              students: []
          }
        };
      }

      
    componentDidMount() {
        
        fetch('http://localhost:8080/teacher')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(teachers => this.setState({teachers: teachers}));
    }

    handleFirstName = (e) => {
        this.setState({firstName: e.target.value});
    }
    handleLastName = (e) => {
        this.setState({lastName: e.target.value});
    }
    handleEmail = (e) => {
        this.setState({email: e.target.value});
    }
    handlePassword = (e) => {
        this.setState({password: e.target.value});
    }

    signUp = () => {
        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              Accept: 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({firstName: this.state.firstName , lastName: this.state.lastName, email: this.state.email , password: this.state.password}),
          };
          fetch("/teacher/signup", requestOptions)
          .then((response) => {
            return response.json();
          })
          .then(() => {
                fetch('http://localhost:8080/class')
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(teachers => this.setState({teachers: teachers}));
          })
          .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err)
          })
    }

    render() {
        // const teachers = this.state.teachers.map(teacher => <div key={teacher._id}>{teacher.firstName} - {teacher.lastName}</div>);
        const teachers = []
        for (let i = 0; i < this.state.teachers.length; i++) {
            teachers.push({label: this.state.teachers[i].firstName + ' ' + this.state.teachers[i].lastName})
        }
        return (
            <div>
            <div className="container">
            <div className="row" style={{marginTop: "100px"}}>
              <div className="col-md-4"></div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                <Select placeholder="Select teacher"options={ teachers } />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4"></div>
              
            </div>
            
          </div>
                        <div></div>
                        <div style={{display: "flex", alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", marginTop: "100px"}}><h5>Signup:</h5></div>
                        <div style={{margin: "20px auto", borderTop: "2px solid black", width: "400px", textAlign: "center"}}>
                        <form style={{marginTop: "30px"}} onSubmit={(event) => {
                            event.preventDefault()
                            this.signUp(this.state.teacher)
                        }} >
                                <input style={{textAlign: "center"}} type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="First Name" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstName} />
                                <div></div>
                                <br></br>
                                <input style={{textAlign: "center"}} type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last Name" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleLastName}/>
                                <div></div>
                                <br></br>
                                <input style={{textAlign: "center"}} type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleEmail}/>
                                <div></div>
                                <br></br>
                                <input style={{textAlign: "center"}} type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePassword}/>
                                <div></div>
                                <br></br>
                                <input className="button button2" type="submit" />
                        </form>
                        </div>
                        </div>
        );
      }
}

export default Teacher;
```

And the webpack, that is proxying the requests:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/index.js"),
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: ["babel-loader"],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i, 
        use: ["file-loader"]
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["*", ".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV,
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  // [webpack-dev-server] "hot: true" automatically applies HMR plugin, you don't have to add it manually to your webpack configuration.
  plugins: [new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()],
  devServer: {
    
    // contentBase is deprecated by static in webpack v5
    proxy: {
      '/': 'http://localhost:3000/',
    },
    // contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "./docs"),
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: I apologize, I now realize that the question title should be "Unable to render react page, instead showing raw data after refresh"

Comment: can you share `teacher` component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is how you have configured your server.js file

```
app.use('/teacher', authRoutes);
app.use('/class', classRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../docs/index.html"))

})
```

Now imagine you are sending request to your server to fetch the data in url `/teacher` now it is doing it's job perfectly fine. Because, it would come across the first line and send you the raw json and be done with it.

One solution would be to keep all your api modules in an '/api' appended path. So, they don't conflict with your regular routing.

```
app.use('/api/teacher', authRoutes);
app.use('/api/class', classRoutes);
app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../docs/index.html"))

})
```

This should solve your issue.

EDIT:
Last route should always return home page. So,  a star is needed in path-matching

```
app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../docs/index.html"))

})
```

Comment: I did try that first, Singh3y. Unfortunately, after editing code to your suggestion, it is not returning the raw data anymore, but proceeds to a global error handler and returns error 404 -> not found.

Comment: Have you updated your componentDidMount's fetch function to `fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/teacher')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(teachers => this.setState({teachers: teachers}));`. If yes can you check what you're getting in response

Comment: Yes. Changed the Teacher componentDidMount, teacher relevant code in server.js to `app.use('/api/teacher', authRoutes);`, also `<Route>` paths and links in App.jsx. Ends up doing exactly the same thing as before.

Comment: I also tried `historyApiFallback: true, hot: true` in webpack, didn't work.

Comment: No, you don't have to update your routes path in react app. Just the server code and componentDidMount. The main thing i was trying to tell was to avoid conflicting routes for your api and react navigation

Comment: Ok, following your response -> on the first render - all is normal. Upon refresh - GET http://localhost:8080/teacher 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Cool! That's expected Now put a star at the `app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "../docs/index.html"))

})` This would send you home page no matter what the path is as react app are intended to work

Comment: OH MY GOD! OH MY GOD! 3 hours spent on this and it is finally working. What was the problem? Thank you, thank you THANK YOU!!!

Comment: One was the api and the last route one which i updated in my answer :)

Comment: Thank you! Now I can see what is the difference between an entry level developer and a mid or senior. :) Now, just one more question, to completely be sure: http://localhost:8080/teacher works like a charm even after refresh, but if I manually type the URL http://localhost:8080/api/teacher, it returns raw data. How can I prevent this? Does it have anything to do with my method? `exports.teacherList = (req, res, next) => {
    Teacher.find()
    .then(teacher => {
        return res.send(teacher)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}`

Comment: No, it should return raw json at that endpoint. Because, if it doesn't return raw json how will you parse it in your application and show data. One solution to avoid showing it in browser is to make the end point accessable using POST method

Comment: That sounds logical. Do you have any advice in how should I proceed, so I can disable user to access the raw data? Again, thank you for all of your help!

Comment: You can set it in post method then users can't access it directly in browser. One more thing your average user will not dig around the website url and a person who is digging around can access it directly from network. So, don't worry too much. If it's not something sensitive. If it is switch the request to post with an authentication middleware in between request

Answer (score 0):

your sever is running on localhost 8080, so might be client is running on localhost something else like 3030 please check that because as i am seeing that you're calling server api on 8080.

you can optimise your code this -

```
          <Route path='/class' element={()=><ClassComponent teacher={this.state.teachers} />} />
          <Route path='/teacher' element={()=><TeacherComponent teacher={this.state.teachers/>} />
```

try this & please upload the ClassComponent and TeacherComponent as well.

Comment: I don't think that would work Madan since I am not rendering based on a state, but based on a database. I also uploaded Teacher component. Thank you for you suggestion!